# How to detect and set a web browser as default web browser in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to verify in javascript, if the current web browser is the default web browser? If not, how to set it as default web browser programmatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? Even if you could (you can't), just don't.

Comment: for interaction with other webapps (metro apps); If my current browser sends info to my metro app (URI + parameters) and then my metro app wants to send back info to same app whom invoked it (opened in web browser) my metro app will send data through URL (encrypted URL) by opening the link on my default browser, thats why I'd like to set my web browser as my default web browser before sending data to my metro app